# Changing the position of an item in wxListBox

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, wxwidgets

I would like to ask you how to dynamically change the position of an item in wxListBox (e.g. drag & drop)
I've only found how to insert the item into wxListBox from wxWidget sample (downloaded with wxWidgets) called dnd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to start with a precisely stated requiremet.

1. User selects item in listbox to be moved
2. User indicates he wants to drag the item to a new position
3. User selects item in listbox to be replaced with dragged item
4. Application rearranges items in list box as requested.

Step 1 seems straightforward.  I imagine you don't need help with that?

Step 2 is the trickiest.  You will need to handle mouse events so as to detect when the user is dragging the mouse through the items.  Here is the docs for the mouse event class http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_mouse_event.html  You will ned to understand most of this in order to pull off this trick!

Step 3 is also tricky. When the user releases the button after the drag, you will need to get the mouse position from the event and calculate which item was under the mouse when the button was released.  You need a HitTest method.  Does the wxListBox have one?  I suspect not!  Perhaps you should consider using wxListCtrl, rather than trying to build your own.  http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ac346d7aa18722fb54580d4c4ed5cf113

Step 4. Now, after all the mouse handling, you should have the moved item and the item to be inserted either before or after ( your call )  Clear the list box and then insert the items in the new order.

All this seems like a great deal of trouble.  Is this feature all that important?  Could you accept a simpler user interface that would get the job done with a fraction of the coding and testing and debugging this will require?

Something like this:

1. User selects item to move
2. User selects to move item up or down ( up/down arrow keys, left/right mouse button, scroll wheel are all possibilities )
3. Application moves selected item up or down
4. User repeats until item is in required position

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to allow the user to reorder the items in a listbox, consider using [wxEditableListBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_editable_list_box.html). If you really need drag and drop, it should be possible to implement it as explained in ravenspoint's answer, but it's more difficult.